# get package version to cpp

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal

When parsing source codes with c preprocessor enabled, the parser doesn't like undefined macros like `MIN_VERSION_packagename(a,b,c)`. How can I get cabal/ghc tell cpp the package info and add the macro definitons?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the very idiomatic (/s) options:

```
ghc -optP-include -optPdist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h
```

I happen to have just been writing a pull request to doctest about this, you may be interested in referencing it:

https://github.com/sol/doctest/pull/109/files#diff-438bc19bd41887f8cacb796eaa990b0aR81

Comment: I got `fatal error: dist/build/autogen/cabal_macros.h: No such file or directory`. From the source I see it's looking for `HASKELL_DIST_DIR`, do I not have it?

Comment: Depends: are you using a cabal sandbox? If so, I can't help you, I don't know where it stores things. If you're using stack, try running `stack path --dist-dir`.

Comment: unfortunately I am using sandbox. but thanks anyways